# How to make a event listener temporarily pause?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("ping")) {
    message.channel.send('Pong!');
  }
});
```

How to add a cooldown(not user specific), so that once this event is triggered, it sleeps for 60 seconds?

Comment: what you're looking for is called "debounce" with a timeout of 60 seconds. It's a really common pattern, so you could find it easily by googling, I think.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/

Comment: @tjb1982 — Debouncing is a more complex problem then this is asking about. Debouncing would send the response 60s after the incoming message unless there was another incoming message in the meantime (which resets the clock). This is much simpler.

Comment: Seems to me you would most likely want to answer `ping`s right away. Maybe you should look into sending `ping`s every 60 seconds instead. But that's just me assuming it's the typical `ping/pong` scenario.

Comment: @Quentin that's not true. Debounce can easily be designed to react immediately and ignore further events for some period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform the action, set a variable, outside the function, to `true`.

Abort the function if it is `true`.

Use `setTimeout` to set it back to `false`.

```js
let cooldown = false;

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("ping")) {
    if (cooldown) return;
    cooldown = true;
    setTimeout(() => { cooldown = false; }, 60000);
    message.channel.send('Pong!');
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't want it to respond 60 seconds later. Instead just don't listen to the event at all.

Comment: @AnushShetty I know. That’s what the code in this answer does.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a debounce. It might seem like overkill in this situation, but the concept is definitely worth learning, and you can use this sort of thing over and over in a codebase without having to declare separate timeout variables outside of each handler's scope.

The following implementation was adapted from https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    let timeout;

    return function(...args) {
        const context = this;
        const later = () => {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate)
                func.apply(context, args);
        };
        const callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

        if (callNow)
            func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

You can use it like

```
client.on("message", debounce(message => {...}, 60 * 1000, true));
```

N.B., it's important that `debounce` returns a `function` and not a `() => {...}` because `func` may be expecting a meaningful `this` context, which can only be bound for `function` functions.